# Accessing elements returned by ego function in R

Tags: r, neighbours

I am using ego function to find the immediate neighbors of node *i*.

```
nbr <- ego(graph1, 1, i)
print(nbr)
```

The print statement outputs:

```
[[1]]
+ 4/1000 vertices:
[1] 119 95 237 276
```

How can I access an integer from the list: 119 95 237 276?

Comment: can u write little more details about what are u looking for. Is it something like you want to see the output in integer, `as.integer()` type of function?

Comment: That kind of answered my question.The function as.integer() is what i was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: so your problem solved, best of luck.